# Opening many large SAS files in R

Tags: r, import, sas

I have 38 SAS files (300MB each) which I open with the read.xport function from the foreign library. I open them in the following way:

```
library(foreign)
library(plyr)
my.files <- list.files(pattern="*.xpt")
list_of_data = llply(filenames, read.xport)
```

This works perfect when I only have up to 4 files, but for all 38 I get a memory overload (obsiously) because R wants to store them all in one list file. I understand that this is what llply is supposed to do. Is there a way to import all .xpt files as a seperate data.frame or data.table? That I just have 38 objects.

What could also cause the memory overload is that the data has got 3000 variables (columns), and I only need 30. Maybe it is possible to import the file, keep those 30 variables and import the next file. I know how to do this line by line, but I would like to write it in a loop.

```
file_one <- read.xport("file1.xpt")
file_one_selection <- data.frame(date=file_one$date,bank=file_one$bank.... etc)
rm(file_one)
```

Many thanks in advance.
Best regards,

Tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read in one file:

```
library(foreign)
d1 <- read.xport("file1.xpt")
```

If this doesn't open the item correctly as a data frame, you could modify to:

```
d1 <- read.xport(as.data.frame("file1.xpt"))
```

If your sas files are called something similar, like file1 - file38, you could loop over them with something like:

```
for(i in 1:38){
  assign(paste("d", i, sep = ""),
    eval(read.xport(paste0("file", i, ".xpt"))))
}
```

If these are not suitable please paste an example data frame or other minimally reproducible example.

Comment: I tried your code: Many thanks for  your help Phil. I tried your second code (without the column selection) on 2 files: file1.xpt and file2.xpt but it does not work... `for(i in 1:2){
  paste0("d", i) <- read.xport(as.name(paste0("file", i, ".xpt"))) But I get the error message: Error in lookup.xport(file) : `first argument must be a file name`. I'll add an example to my initial question.
} `

Comment: Hi @TimBenschop, if I could have one of your files (I can duplicate it) I can check the code and edit my post.

Comment: Hi @Phil, files are free to download from [link]http://www.chicagofed.org/webpages/banking/financial_institution_reports/commercial_bank_structure_data.cfm If this is not what you meant, let me know.